# html: how to start with a space in title

Tags: html

It seems the **starting** &nbsp was ignored in the title tag.

Demo below:

```
 <title>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;pika</title>
```

I wondered is there a way to hack this, maybe using a foreign character which looks like a space? Any advice?

Comment: Seems to work in FF and IE, but not in Chrome.

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is a completely reasonable question

Comment: i test it, with Firefox and IE its working, but not working on Chrome.. now can u plz explain the reason for this requirement???

Comment: Why would you want/need to do this?

Comment: Adding `\u200B` (zero-width space) in the beginning of the title text seems to show the extra spacing in Chrome too. To utilize this, the _file_ must be UTF8 encoded.

Answer (score 4):

There are potential reasons for doing this.  Especially if search engines isn't a consideration.  In a web app, you may want to dynamically change the title for effect, for example.

In the situation I had, we wanted to flash an emoji if you moved to another tab and activity occurred on the hidden tab. Were only using Chrome and this worked for us. Getting the spacing right is still a trick.

The character `&#6158;` is called a Mongolian space and is not strictly considered a space character for classification purposes.  I found that if you lead with this, you can put whatever you want after, for example:

```
<title>&#6158;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Title</title>
```

Answer (score 3):

No, you shouldn't format the title in any way.

It's just information to the browser, that it will display outside the page itself. Typically it's shown in the name of the browser or on the tab for the page.

**Do you really think spaces is a good solution? What will happen with different screen resolutions? How spaces will behave on tabs?**

Comment: He didn't ask about formatting it. Only about a way to add whitespace to the beginning of the title. This doesn't necessarily need formatting

Comment: @GustvandeWal Do you really think spaces is a good solution? What will happen with different screen resolutions? How spaces will behave on tabs?

Comment: @AnkiiG Like Gust has stated, OP's question doesn't have anything to do with formatting. OP just wants to use some HTML escapes in the title.

Comment: @AnkiiG How does this have **anything** to do with screen resolutions?

Comment: Modern browsers that use tabs shows the first few characters of the title only anyway … and putting multiple spaces in front of the title would even increase this usability problem. And prefixing the title with a number of spaces _is_ a sort of “formatting” in my eyes.